# Under which conditions $\int_0^\infty q^{1-k} J_{2m+k} (q) J_\nu (qr) \, \mathrm{d} q $ vanishes if $r>1$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, bessel-functions

Consider the following infinite integral 
$$
\int_0^\infty q^{1-k} J_{2m+k} (q) J_\nu (qr) \, \mathrm{d} q \, , 
$$
where $\nu \in \{0,1\}$ and $m$ being a positive integer.
Here $k$ and $r$ are both positive real number.
I would like to make use of this integral for solving a physical situation involving dual integral equations.

My question is: under which conditions this integral vanishes in the case $r>1$.

It would be great if someone here could provide with some hints that could help a bit.

Thanks!

R

Comment: For $\nu=0$ the integral seems to vanish under the prescribed hypothesis. But how about $\nu=1$?

Comment: This one probably what you look for http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22#E62

Comment: @KostiantynLapchevskyi Yes thanks a lot. I will have a read on that.

Comment: @KostiantynLapchevskyi The fact is that the integral above cannot be cast into the integral you mentioned. Here $q^{1-k}$ is independent of the order of Bessel functions..

Comment: There is also http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22#E56, which fully match all variety, but I don't think it's really helpful, unlike E62, which shows conditions for integral to become $0$

Comment: @KostiantynLapchevskyi E62 looks very helpful. I have simply changed the exponent of $q$ is the above integral into $1-k+\nu-2m$ instead of $1-k$ and the integral indeed vanishes for $r>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take into account [following equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22#E62):
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}t^{\mu-\nu+1}J_\mu (at)J_\nu(bt)dt=0,\quad \text{if }0<b<a,\\
\text{when }\Re(\nu)>\Re(\mu)>-1 \tag{1}
$$
While equation of interest:
$$
\int_0^\infty q^{1-k} J_{2m+k} (q) J_\nu (qr) \, \mathrm{d} q \tag{2}
$$
As $m$ is positive integer and $k$ is positive real number, while $\nu\in\{0,1\}$, it is obvious that $\Re(2m+k)>\Re(\nu)$. Thus, for the sake of convenience let us rename variables: 
$$
q\to t,\quad \nu\to\mu,\quad 2m+k\to\nu,\quad 1-k\to1-\nu+2m
$$

$$
\int_0^\infty t^{2m-\nu+1} J_\mu (tr) J_{\nu} (t)  \, \mathrm{d} t \tag{3}
$$
So, here we have $\Re(\nu)>\Re(\mu)>-1$ and $0<b<a$, where $b=1,a=r>1$. Only thing we need is to have hten is $2m=\mu$, but it is not the case, as $m$ is positive integer, while $\mu\in\{0,1\}$. Thus, to vanish according to the mentioned formula, initial integral should have different power of $q$.

It can be mentioned in comments $q^{1-k-2m+\nu}$, then integral vanish for all $\nu\in\{0,1\}$. Generally, it is $q^{1-k-2m+\epsilon}$, where $\epsilon\in\{0,1\}$ and integral vanish only if $\epsilon=\nu$, assumed that $\epsilon$ fixed and we vary $\nu$. (All definitions in this paragraph given in terms of initial variables).